# Keep attribute value outside of method scope

Tags: c#, static

I have a `skiPlan` class that has a `private static int lastNumber` and a `private int number` field.

Inside the class I have a method like this

```
public void upLastNumberByOne()
{
    lastnumber++; // Increment the lastNumber by 1
}
```

The constructor of the object is the following:

```
public skiPlan() 
{ 
  upLastNumberByOne(); 
  this.number= lastnumber;
}
```

here is the thing:

Each time  I create a `skiPlan` object the value of the `lastNumber`-field must be incremented by 1.

I have found a way to do this using the `Interlocked` class.

The question is, how can I do it without it?

Comment: Without more context, it's impossible to know for sure what answer you need. If your code is single-threaded, you don't need `Interlocked` at all. You can just increment the field as you've shown above. If the `upLoadNumberByOne()` method can be called concurrently by two or more threads, then you need _some_ kind of synchronization, and `Interlocked` is the best in this scenario. Why _wouldn't_ you want to use it? There are other mechanisms, but no good reason to choose any rather than `Interlocked`. Your question isn't very clear. What is your actual _goal_ here? What _problem_ do you have?

Comment: The code is single threaded, I have not yet learned how to code multi-threaded applications. The goal is to have a constructor that get the lastNUmber value and increment it by 1 using the method above. the probleme i'm facing is that when the object has been created the value of the lastNumber property gets back to zero. therfor, I'm looking for a way to keep the value throughout my objects instanciations. the result would be object1.lastnumber = 1 and when I instanciate the object for a second time it would be object2.lastnumber = object1.lastnumber + 1.

Comment: I can´t see any way for your application to reset `lastNumber` to zero when it is static and your app is single-threaded. Maybe you set the `lastNumber` to zero somewhere else?

Comment: Is the number of ski plan objects a known value? Have you looked at any design patterns that can manage the creation and therefore inject an incremental value, for example the factory pattern?  Or the façade pattern and remove the incrementation responsibility out of the ski plan making it a simple DTO instead?

Comment: If you are making multiples there is likely a collection involved(?) Increment the value based on the collection count when they are added.  Otherwise, no idea what you are playing at

Comment: _"The code is single threaded"_ -- then you don't need `Interlocked`. Your question is also misleading, as you neglected to include the question you _actually_ need an answer to, i.e. why the code you have doesn't work, along with a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces _that_ problem. There is no way to answer this question as stated.

Comment: I was mistaking all along, I had in fact initialized the static variable to 0, which resulted in the value resetted to 0 each time i created an object. Sorry for the inconvenience, I'll try to do better next time. Thanks for your help guys !

Answer (score 0):

You could change "private" into "public" for the declaration of lastnumber and number and refer to the skiPlan class instead of an instance of it.

Comment: This answer makes no sense. The accessibility of the field is irrelevant, and assuming by _"refer to the skiPlan class"_ you mean using the class name to access some member, the way one accesses a class member is dictated by whether the member is static or non-static, and referring to it some other way won't affect what the code actually _does_. Never mind does this answer not in any way address the question being asked, nor the question that _should_ have been asked. What question do you think the above _does_ answer?